# How to get telegram user access_hash with only using userid?

Tags: c#, telegram

I am creating telegram bot and telegram integrated app which creates chat groups. Application creates chat group and adds users and bot to channel.

I want to add users outside of contact list using similar workflow

1. App creates chat group and adds bot to channel.
2. App adds selected users to channel and we know only user_id

Some times users will be added and some times users are not added.

After some researching it seems that users access_hash might be needed in order to invite users to channel.

Is there a way to get users access_hash or is there another way of adding users to channel?

As for the app I am using OpenTL client api
https://github.com/OpenTl/OpenTl.ClientApi

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but access_hash was found under userDialogs

```
    var userDialogs = await this.client.MessagesService.GetUserDialogsAsync(100);
    foreach (TUser user in userDialogs.Users.Items)
    {
        var AccessHash = user.AccessHash;
    }
```

This contains all users from messages and groups

https://core.telegram.org/constructor/messages.dialogs